# Identifier isn't declared in the current scope in godot

Tags: godot

Code for the coin to make a score:

```
extends Area2D


onready var anim_player: AnimationPlayer = get_node("AnimationPlayer")


func _on_body_entered(body: PhysicsBody2D) -> void:
    picked()
    
    
    
func picked() -> void:
    PlayerData.Score += score
    anim_player.play("Fade")
```

It isn't working in coin but works in enemy(code):

```
extends "res://Code/Both Script.gd"

onready var Stomp_Thingy: Area2D = $Stomp_Thingy


export var score: = 100

func _ready() -> void:
    set_physics_process(false)
    _Velocity.x = -Speed.x


func _on_Stomp_Thingy_body_entered(body: PhysicsBody2D) -> void:
    if body.global_position.y > get_node("Stomp Thingy").global_position.y:
        return
    get_node("CollisionShape2D").disabled = true
    queue_free()

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    _Velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if is_on_wall():
        _Velocity.x *= -1.0
    _Velocity.y = move_and_slide(_Velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL).y
    
    
func die() -> void:
    queue_free()enter code here
    PlayerData.Score += score
```

Comment: "It isn't working" isn't a good problem description. What is the identifier that isn't declared? Where do you get that message? Edit: Is it "PlayerData"? I suspect that is supposed to be an [autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html) (If you are following a tutorial, you may have skipped that part). I'll also remind you to connect your signals (just in case that is what you mean by "It isn't working"). StackOverflow expect you to explain the problem, this is why it demands some text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In script for coin, i think "score" isn't declared. So you can add "var score = 100" to that script. Or use autoload if you want score same on enemy and coin. Include more information.

Comment: Thanks I actuallywote the scit again and it worked I think t was cursed then lol thanks fo help